# Suspicious namespace: should start with http://

Tags: android, xml

**Problem Appeared :** When i have open my **XML** file and changing the `layout_height` attribut.

**Problem description :** `Suspicious namespace: should start with http://`

**Line problem* :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:pj="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.example"
    xmlns:bm="com.example"      <!-- problem line  -->
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/basic"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clean your project and if the problem persist restart your IDE

Answer (score 5):

If you need a custom namespace, use the Android auto-namespace feature.

In your example:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" />
```